# Is there a way to change .xcconfig files per scheme in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I currently have a project setup with one target and multiple build configurations (DEBUG, STAGING, RELEASE). Each build configuration has a corresponding .xcconfig file for the one target/scheme. I would like to keep the project at one target, and add a second scheme that would use a different set of .xcconfig files for the 3 build configurations. Is there a way to swap out those .xcconfig references at build time on a per-scheme basis without having to set up a separate target for the 2nd scheme?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do this, and any way you'd design would tend to be really fragile. The usual solution is to have more build configurations. If you want two kinds of Debug, you just create Debug-Options1 and Debug-Options2 and give them different xcconfig files. Is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RobNapier. This is going to start as a proof of concept, and for 2 schemes your idea would work no problem. The issue I could see with that approach comes up at scale (which is the end-goal) - let's say in a year we have 50-100 schemes. I get the feeling maintaining all of those build configurations could turn into a nightmare at that point.

Comment: 50-100 schemes sounds like a questionable use of schemes (the menu would be overwhelming). I'd look instead at commandline builds with `xcodebuild` and pass `-xcconfig`. 50-100 schemes doesn't buy you a lot over 50-100 targets IMO.

Comment: Oh man, good idea - I hadn't even considered just handling it all via my CI environment.

Answer (score 1):

OK I came up with this solution that will work with any CI setup that allows you to execute a post-clone / pre-build script:

I created 3 `.xcconfig` files called `Default-DEBUG.xcconfig`, `Default-STAGING.xcconfig`, and `Default-RELEASE.xcconfig`. Those are then associated with the target's configurations via Xcode.

In the post-clone phase I have a script that takes the name of the scheme, looks for a matching `.xcconfig` file (named the same as the scheme), and copies it over to replace the appropriate Default one.